# User friendly Mac OS Tool for viewing and editing mySQL data

Tags: mysql

I'm searching for a way to display mySQL DB Data offline on my mac. What I need is a (free or cheap) Tool where I can display, filter, search and **edit** a list/view of db data (selected via an sql query). A DB Administration tool can do this, but not user friendly.
A great existing tool is metabase but I don't need the functional scope and you cannot edit data there.

Any help is welcome! Thanks!

Comment: This is usually called an "application" and is custom written for the problem domain of the database.

Comment: This question should rather go to: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.